# Global Local Variables in exec function Python

Tags: python

I am building a small website using Streamlit, so the user has the option to edit the website add their own widgets and all, for example:

```py
a=0
b=0
dot=a*b
h1(dot)
code = User writes his/her code
*that codes starts executing from here*
```

however I am facing a problem while testing the website
I came up with this solution:

```py
a=0
b=0
dot=a*b
h1(dot)
code = code_editor()

exec(code)
```

I gave a code like this:

```py
a=0
def update():
    a=a*a
update()
```

[Just for example]

Unfortunately I got this error saying that `a` variable is not defined ,later I edited that code

```py
a=0
def update():
    global a
    a=a*a
update()
```

And it worked usual , but I would not like to always add `global a`, I think this is a problem with `exec` I heard people saving their variables generated in a dictionary parsing them later but the user can write of 100s of lines of code and I cannot save all that to dictionary most examples have a function like `exec('a=2')` in that case I can hardcode and store `a` to a dictionary but here I have a much complex problem where I am executing the users code, which is not that simple. How can I create the local variable dictionary on a code like this:

```py
n=10
output=1
for x in range(n):
    output*=n
    n=n-1
```

Or else do I have anything else to do?

Comment: Provide `locals()` to `exec`: `exec(code, locals=locals())`.

Comment: Tried it did not work

Comment: *What* did not work? If I `exec` your code `"""a=0; def update(): a=a*a; update()"""` it doesn't throw an error on my machine.